# My code does not work without that specific line. Why?

Tags: ruby, chomp

```
puts "Enter the first number"
num1 = Float(gets)

puts "Enter the second number"
num2 = Float(gets)

puts "Enter the operation"
op = gets
op = op.chomp # <--- THIS LINE!

case op 
when "+" then puts num1 + num2
when "-" then puts num1 - num2    
when "*" then puts num1 * num2    
when "/" then puts num1 / num2
end
```

Comment: Just `p(op)` before `chomp` and see what the string really is.

Comment: Every method you can call on a String is documented. You could have answered your own question by [reading the documentation for `String#chomp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/String.html#method-i-chomp) to find out what it does.

Comment: @Jordan While it's true that the question could be answered by debugging plus reading the docs, that alone does not necessarily make it a bad question for SO.  I mention it because I'm seeing this sort of comment pop up lately in a way that implies that anything answerable through documentation should not be asked here.  That's not true.  That said, this question does currently have other problems that need to be fixed before it is a good SO question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When entering the "+" operation, you hit two keys, <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>return</kbd>. Both produce a character, resulting in `"+\n"`. (that `\n` is a newline character)

`chomp` removes the newline character.

Comment: Thank you got it !

Comment: @Jesus you're welcome! It's a common pitfall when using `gets` for the first time :-)